# Nginx as Reverse Proxy for Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have nginx running as reverse proxy for apache for my website. The problem I have is that all the logs in apache have 127.0.0.1 as the IP address. I have these set in nginx.conf

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;

# Set the hostname
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

#Set the forwarded-for header.
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Install and configure [`rpaf` module for Apache](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/). For example, see [this blog post](http://kirkdesigns.co.uk/nginx-proxy-apache-access-remote-host-ip-address-using-modpraf)